# Build & Install OpenSceneGraph-3.1.3 give me a No WindowSystemInterface error?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, openscenegraph

I am trying to install the latest SVN Update `OpenSceneGraph-3.1.4` on *Mac OS X Mountain Lion*.

Do I need to install a specific *WindowSystemInterface* ?

```
$ osgviewer cow.osg

View::setUpViewAcrossAllScreens() : Error, no WindowSystemInterface available, cannot create windows.
Viewer::realize() - failed to set up any windows.
```

I build and re-build many times, using CMake with or without Gui, compiling Unix files or from within Xcode, but still same problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you'd like a more recent Mac OSG binary which includes a
>   user-runnable installer, OSG Frameworks supporting both 32 and 64-bit
>   archs, etc. you can use the one published by ARToolworks:
>
> http://www.artoolworks.com/dist/openscenegraph/3.1.x/
>
> It doesn't include the COLLADA (.dae) plugin but most other plugins
>   are present.
>
> Regards,  Phil.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somehow the `GraphicsWindow*.cpp` file didn't compile and link and execute, as this is what provides the `WindowSystemInterface`. This is an unusual condition, as normally this is built automatically, linked in and executed as the library starts up and the user is never the wiser.

I'm not sure what to advise you, only to re-check you build process as something has gone very wrong.

Comment: I am using the latest SVN version available `OpenSceneGraph-3.1.4`.